# WForm, как нарисовать поле для крестиков-ноликов 100*100

Tags: c#, winforms

Использую Windows Form. Подскажите какие элементы нужны и как правильно разбить их на квадраты. Нужно отобразить всё поле и дать возможность пользователю отметить не заполненный квадрат. Есть идея сделать поле с помощью Panel и picture box-ов, но проблема как всё разметить

Comment: TableLayoutPanel как основу, а в ячейках по ситуации, можно Button-ы например, или Label-ы. Можно на обычной Panel просто все руками нарисовать. Вариантов масса, давайте конкретику

Comment: а вы все поле целиком отображать собираетесь? допишите в [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/881847/edit) все важные детали, а также что уже пробовали, что не получилось или почему не подошло.

Comment: 10к самостоятельных контролов это конечно перебор, будет жутко тормозить. Я бы вручную нарисовал поле на Bitmap с последующим выводом картинки на форме, только не в PictureBox, он для такого не предназначен. Проверка положения мыши при клике по координатам с пересчетом в координаты изображения с дорисовкой в нужном месте подходящего символа. Ну и двойная буферизация для защиты от мерцания. Как-то так. Ну и само собой, игровое поле и его состояния должны быть в отдельном классе, который моделирует вашу игру и ничего не знает о том, кто и как будет его отображать.